# WebRTC's Statistics API - estimatedPlayoutTimestamp giving incorrect values

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming

I'm currently investigating the WebRTC Statistics API, specifically the identifiers *lastPacketReceivedTimestamp* and *estimatedPlayoutTimestamp*. My aim for this is to evaluate when exactly the WebRTC API receives an RTP packet of video data and when exactly that packet is utilised to render a frame of video.

I can convert the values for *lastPacketReceivedTimestamp* from High Resolution Time to human-readable format, but I am struggling to do so with *estimatedPlayoutTimestamp* values.

Example outputs for *lastPacketReceivedTimestamp* are 1648396983645,1648396984656,1648396985657,1648396986656 -  these convert well on https://www.epochconverter.com/.

Example outputs for *estimatedPlayoutTimestamp* are 3857385783571,3857385784570,3857385785580,3857385786570 - these do not convert well, instead reading as many years in the future.

Am I misunderstanding what the values of *estimatedPlayoutTimestamp* are? I thought they would just be the timestamp of when each packet is used in a render, but this does not appear to be the case. How should I go about finding when exactly each packet is used to render a frame of WebRTC video?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

estimatedPlayoutDelayTimestamp is defined as a NTP timestamp in [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcinboundrtpstreamstats-estimatedplayouttimestamp). These start on January 1st 1900, causing it to be 70 years in the future if you consider it to be based on the epoch.

Note that chrome://webrtc-internals currently does the calculation wrong as well...

Comment: Hi Philipp - yes I should have mentioned that I got these results from chrome://webrtc-internals! That's good to know though, thank you - I'll maybe try get the results directly from the getStats() API. Thanks!